# convert stream file of iText PDF not opening MS word

Tags: itext, itext7

Our project has requirement to generate end report both in PDF and MS-Word Document. We are using iTextSharp to dynamically generate tables and rows in report. Finally we will upload the file to server as PDF and MS-word. Both will be converted to Byte Array/Stream file and saved as PDF and MS-Word Document. **In Which,uploaded PDF working as expected, but MS-word getting error and not opening(Attaching the screen shot).**[image]

Comment: Questions without a code snippet are usually not eligible to be posted on Stack Overflow. Please show us your code. We need to see how you create an MS Word document using iTextSharp.

Answer (score 1):

iTextSharp doesn't produce MS Word documents, so this isn't an actual iText question. When I look at your screen shot, I see that you are trying to import a PDF file into Word. Since Word can't interpret PDF syntax, it shows you the syntax of the PDF file:

```
%PDF-1.4
%âãÏÓ
1 0 obj
<</Type/Font...
```

I think your question is wrong. You are *not* using iTextSharp to create a PDF file and an MS Word file. You are using iTextSharp to create a PDF file, and **not** an MS Word file.

There is no such thing as "Save a PDF as MS Word file" in iTextSharp, and it will be extremely difficult to find another tool that can convert a PDF document to a Word document in an acceptable way. (There are such tools, but the quality is suboptimal for PDFs that weren't made to be converted to another format.)

Comment: We are using iText sharp library to generate the contents (Tables, image printing, line of text), which satisfies our requirement to generate report. We are using iTextsharp library properties like (Chunks, paragraphs, fonts etc.,). Whatever report we generated using iText sharp features, we will convert that as stream and save it as PDF and Word document using C#. Finally, while downloading those PDF and Word documents, PDF works as expected. But word doesn't. :(

Comment: You write *we will convert that as stream and save it as PDF and Word document using C#.* The first part is correct: you can save a stream created with iTextSharp as PDF. However, **you can not save such a stream as a Word document.** Suppose that I have a radio, and I say: that radio is great for listening to music, but something must be wrong because I can't watch my TV-show on my radio. That is perfectly normal **because a radio is NOT A TV!** Just like iTextSharp is a library for creating PDF, **but not for creating MS Word documents!**